# Is there a way to retrieve deleted progress for skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I played on the xbox 360 edition of skyrim with the dawnguard and dragonborn DLC. I deleted my progress last summer by accident that was on my flash drive while clearing space. I haven't been playing since that. I got a hard drive so I can store that data again. I want to play it again but I don't want to start over because I had the best stuff and I invested a lot of time in it. If there is a way to retrieve that progress in any sort of way that doesn't cost money please tell me. I wouldn't prefer to use money but if it is the only than I'll have to resort to that.

Comment: While I may be wrong: No.

Answer (score -1):

No sorry buddy once you delete something like that it's gon for good

Comment: If you disagree with an answer, downvote and move on. No need to get into an argument.

Answer (score -1):

Oh there might be a chance i'm not sure if you have the cloud where you live but where I live it backs up all your memory onto your own personal server so if you have that look there